# Getting Error: Route.get() requires a callback function but got a [object Object] when adding new function in authMiddleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to check whether the user tried to sign-In is admin or not. If isAdmin = true than admin, if isAdmin = false than not. But, when I am trying to export my admin function in  my **authMiddleware.js** I am getting following error
[image]

Everything was working fine before I added admin function and tried to export it in my **authMiddleware.js**. Here is the code:

**authMiddleware.js**

```
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const User = require("../models/userModel");

exports.protect = async (req, res, next) => {
  let token;
  if (
    req.headers.authorization &&
    req.headers.authorization.startsWith("Bearer")
  ) {
    try {
      token = req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1];

      const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);

      req.user = await User.findById(decoded.id).select("-password");
      next();
    } catch (error) {
      error = new Error("Not Authorized!!");
      error.status = 401;
      next(error);
    }
  }

  if (!token) {
    const error = new Error("Not Authorized!!, No Token!!");
    error.status = 401;
    next(error);
  }
};

exports.admin = (req, res, next) => {
  if (req.user && req.user.isAdmin) {
    next();
  } else {
    const error = new Error("Not Authorized As An Admin");
    error.status = 401;
    next(error);
  }
};
```

**userRoutes.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const {
  authUser,
  getUserProfile,
  registerUser,
  updateUserProfile,
  getUsers,
} = require("../controllers/userController");
const { protect, admin } = require("../middleware/authMiddleware");
const router = express.Router();

router.route("/").post(registerUser).get(protect, admin, getUsers);
router.post("/login", authUser);
router
  .route("/profile")
  .get(protect, getUserProfile)
  .put(protect, updateUserProfile);

module.exports = router;
```

**userController.js**

```
const User = require("../models/userModel");
const generateToken = require("../utils/generateToken");

//  @description: Auth user & Get token
//  @route:       POST /api/users/login
//  @access:      Public
exports.authUser = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const { email, password } = req.body;
    const user = await User.findOne({ email });

    if (user && (await user.matchPassword(password))) {
      res.json({
        _id: user._id,
        name: user.name,
        email: user.email,
        isAdmin: user.isAdmin,
        token: generateToken(user._id),
      });
    } else {
      const error = new Error("Invalid email or password");
      error.status = 401;
      next(error);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("_id: ", user._id);
    error = new Error("Invalid user data");
    error.status = 401;
    next(error);
  }
};

//  @description: Register a new User
//  @route:       POST /api/users/users
//  @access:      Public
exports.registerUser = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const { name, email, password } = req.body;
    const userExists = await User.findOne({ email });

    if (userExists) {
      const error = new Error("User already exists");
      error.status = 400;
      next(error);
    }

    const user = await User.create({
      name,
      email,
      password,
    });

    if (user) {
      res.status(201).json({
        _id: user._id,
        name: user.name,
        email: user.email,
        isAdmin: user.isAdmin,
        token: generateToken(user._id),
      });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    error.status = 400;
    next(error);
  }
};

//  @description: Get user profile
//  @route:       GET /api/users/profile
//  @access:      Private
exports.getUserProfile = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.findById(req.user._id);

    if (user) {
      res.json({
        _id: user._id,
        name: user.name,
        email: user.email,
        isAdmin: user.isAdmin,
      });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    error = new Error("User not found");
    error.status = 404;
    next(error);
  }
};

//  @description: Update user profile
//  @route:       PUT /api/users/profile
//  @access:      Private
exports.updateUserProfile = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.findById(req.user._id);
    if (user) {
      user.name = req.body.name || user.name;
      user.email = req.body.email || user.email;

      if (req.body.password) {
        user.password = req.body.password;
      }

      const updatedUser = await user.save();

      res.json({
        _id: updatedUser._id,
        name: updatedUser.name,
        email: updatedUser.email,
        isAdmin: updatedUser.isAdmin,
        token: generateToken(updatedUser._id),
      });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    error = new Error("User not found");
    error.status = 404;
    next(error);
  }
};

//  @description: Get all users
//  @route:       GET /api/users
//  @access:      Private/Admin
exports.getUsers = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.find({});
    res.json(user);
  } catch (error) {
    error = new Error("cant find any user's profile");
    error.status = 404;
    next(error);
  }
};

//  @description: Delete users
//  @route:       DELETE /api/users/:id
//  @access:      Private/Admin
exports.deleteUsers = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.findById(req.params._id);
    if (user) {
      await user.remove();
      res.json({ message: "User Removed" });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    error = new Error("cant find any user's profile");
    error.status = 404;
    next(error);
  }
};
```

Comment: Try putting console.log(protect, admin, getUsers) after const Router. It will help you and us debug this.

Comment: I logged  after `const router = express.Router()` in authMiddleware. and got: `[AsyncFunction (anonymous)] [Function (anonymous)] [AsyncFunction (anonymous)]`

Comment: Are you sure getUserprofile is a function? One suggestion is to atleast move the '/' path functions at the bottom. Otherwise all calls will match that route. This might not solve the issue though

Comment: yes, I have updated the question.

Comment: I dont understand how but your output shows that actually you are getting an array. Can you try to access your imported methods like getUsers[0], protect[0] etc.

Comment: I am getting undefined

Comment: OK, so I don't know why but It wan not accepting `exports.admin` , `exports.protect`. neither it was accepting `module.exports = { admin, protect }`  
So, I created different File for admin check and exported them separately, and it worked. Any Idea why this happening?